# Python How do I stop the code from printing output

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu and I am trying to find out if AIDE is installed. This is my code so far.

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['dpkg', '-s', 'aide'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print(result)
```

After using subprocess.PIPE, the output of the command executed was still being printed onto the python shell.

print(result) gave me this output.

```
CompletedProcess(args=['dpkg', '-s', 'aide'], returncode=1, stdout=b'')
```

How do I put the output of the command executed into a variable and print it only when I need to?

Comment: Is the output you're seeing definitely on stdout and not on stderr?

Comment: Make sure to capture (or redirect) `stderr` as well.

Comment: Add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Yea it works Thanks guys!

Comment: But how do I get the value of the stderr by the way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Popen:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['dpkg', '-s', 'aide'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = process.communicate()

... some code ...

print(output)
```